# Css style active in react components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, npm-package

Alright,so I have SPA without other urls,everything is on one page and I made it when  you click on navbar link it scrolls down to that component.
Now I want to make that link active when they click or when they scroll down to it.
Help appreciated.

I tried onClick function with forEach removing active class on all links and then adding it to the clicked livk via event,but there are weird bugs..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you share some of your code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have it installed

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

[See here for full details](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/start/tutorial.md)

> A  is a special kind of  that knows whether or not it
> is "active". This is useful when building a navigation menu such as a
> breadcrumb or a set of tabs where you'd like to show which of them is
> currently selected. It also provides useful context for assistive
> technology like screen readers.
>
> By default, an active class is added to a  component when it
> is active. This provides the same simple styling mechanism for most
> users who are upgrading from v5. One difference as of v6.0.0-beta.3 is
> that activeClassName and activeStyle have been removed from
> NavLinkProps. Instead, you can pass a function to either style or
> className that will allow you to customize the inline styling or the
> class string based on the component's active state. You can also pass
> a function as children to customize the content of the 
> component based on their active state, specially useful to change
> styles on internal elements.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function NavList() {
  // This styling will be applied to a <NavLink> when the
  // route that it links to is currently selected.
  let activeStyle = {
    textDecoration: "underline",
  };

  let activeClassName = "underline";

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to="messages"
            style={({ isActive }) =>
              isActive ? activeStyle : undefined
            }
          >
            Messages
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to="tasks"
            className={({ isActive }) =>
              isActive ? activeClassName : undefined
            }
          >
            Tasks
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="tasks">
            {({ isActive }) => (
              <span
                className={
                  isActive ? activeClassName : undefined
                }
              >
                Tasks
              </span>
            )}
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

[See here for full details](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#navlink)